# What is expected value of having damaged PC if we choose 4 out of 8, where 3 of them is damaged.

Tags: probability, expected-value

I don't get the logic for this again. So the probability that the PC is damaged is $\frac{3}{8}$ and four random PC are being selected out of these eight. Then the expect value of damaged PC of all 4 selected would be $\frac{3}{8} \cdot 4 = \frac{3}{2}=1.5$. I am not sure if it's correct. I also need to write a mathematical dispersion for this problem and am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you be more clear on the question? What do you mean with 'the expected value of having a damaged PC'? Do you mean the probability of having at least one damaged PC on the 4 chosen ones?

Comment: This logic only works when "a certain PC is damaged" are independent events, as otherwise the probability of a PC is damaged won't be a constant $3/8$. In our example, if you first select a damaged PC, the chance that you get another damaged PC on the second try would be $2/7\neq 3/8$.

Comment: Are the PCs being damage independent of one another?

Comment: Somewhat counter-intuitively to beginners, questions about expected value like this one here do not in fact matter on whether selection is done with or without replacement and the independence of the events.  Regardless of whether or not the selection is independent/with replacement, it will be the case that the probability that the first selected PC is damaged will be $\frac{3}{8}$ and this will be the same as the probability that the second selected pc is damaged and the same as the probability that the third is damaged and so on...(*Note! we are not talking about conditional probabilities*)

Comment: When describing the random variable counting the number of damaged pcs that we selected, we can choose to reinterpret it as a sum of random variables, each of which describes only whether or not their respective individual pc was damaged.  By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of a sum is the sum of the expected values, and so the expected value *is* in fact calculated as simply as $\frac{3}{8}\cdot 4 = 1.5$ and you got the right answer (*even if you couldn't explain why it was correct*).

Answer (score 1):

The term "dispersion" in relation to the statistics of a population is somewhat vague, since there are several well-defined statistical quantities that [may be taken as measures of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion). Assuming that what you're being asked for is the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), $\ \sigma\ $, or equivalently, its square, $\ \sigma^2\ $, the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), you can calculate it from the formula
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left(D^2\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(D\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^3 d^2\mathbb{P}(D=d)-1.5^2\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ D\ $ is the number of damaged PCs in your sample of $4$.

Unfortunately, the observations made in JMoravitz's comments, which enable you to simplify the calculation of $\ \mathbb{E}\left(D\right)\ $, don't help much in the calculation of $\ \mathbb{E}\left(D^2\right)\ $.  If you want to calculate the latter quantity, it doesn't seem possible to avoid having to calculate the probabilities $\  \mathbb{P}(D=d)\ $.  There are $\ 3\choose\ d\ $ subsets of size $\ d\ $ of the set of $3$ damaged PCs, and $\ 5\choose\ 4-d\ $ subsets of size $\ 4-d\ $ of the $5$ undamaged PCs.  Thus, there are $\ {3\choose\,d}{5\choose\ 4-d}\ $ ways of choosing $4$ PCs, exactly $\ d\ $ of which are damaged, from the original set of $8$.  The total number of ways of choosing $4$ PCs from the $8$, which you are apparently supposed to assume are equally likely to have occurred, is $\ 8\choose\ \ 4\ $.  Therefore, $\  \mathbb{P}(D=d)=\frac{{3\choose\,d}{5\choose\ 4-d}}{8\choose\ 4}\ $, and
\begin{align}\sigma^2&=\frac{1^2 {3\choose1}{5\choose 3}+2^2 {3\choose2}{5\choose 2}+3^2 {3\choose 3}{5\choose 1}}{8\choose 4}-1.5^2\\
&=\frac{69}{14}-2.25\\
&\approx 2.68\ ,
\end{align}
and the standard deviation, $\ \sigma\approx1.64\ $